# Need access to current hostname in Capistrano configuration variable for delayed_job named queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job

I'm using named queues within delayed_job to keep tasks isolated by server:

```
subdomain = Socket.gethostname.split('.')[0]
MyModel.delay(:queue => (subdomain + "_queue")).get_some_records
```

When I start delayed_job on each server, I need to set the `--queue` flag.  One can pass arguments to the delayed_job CL with `set :delayed_job_args`.  AFAIK, Capistrano allows for the use of the `$CAPISTRANO:HOST$` in `run` commands, but this doesn't help me with `set`.

As a workaround, I have overridden the delayed_jobs task like this:

```
desc "Start the delayed_job process"
  task :start, :roles => lambda { roles } do
  run "cd #{current_path};#{rails_env} script/delayed_job start --queue=$CAPISTRANO:HOST$_queue #{args}"
end
```

Is there any way to do this as intended, using `set`?  I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
set :delayed_job_args, "--queue=#{ hostname }_queue"
```

**Update**

I discovered another kludgy (and not so DRY) way to do this, but still would like to do it with `set` if possible:

```
desc "Start the delayed_job process"
task :start, :roles => lambda { roles } do
  parallel do |session|
    session.when "server.host =~ /server1/", "cd #{current_path};#{rails_env} script/delayed_job start --queue=server1_queue #{args}"
    session.when "server.host =~ /server2/", "cd #{current_path};#{rails_env} script/delayed_job start --queue=server2_queue #{args}"
    session.else "cd #{current_path};#{rails_env} script/delayed_job restart #{args}"
  end
end
```

Rails 3.2.8, delayed_job 3.0.3, capistrano 2.13.4.

Answer (score 0):

How about … ?

```
set :delayed_job_args, "--queue=#{ $CAPISTRANO:HOST$ }_queue"
```

I have not personally tested this in Cap, but it seems logical.